# How to copy the folder structure and files into the destination using a Windows command?

Tags: windows, cmd, xcopy

How to copy the folder structure and files into the destination using a Windows command?

I tried the below, but the folder test is not copied, but all folders and files were copied:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\hpara\Desktop\Test" "C:\Users\hpara\Desktop/Foo" /E /H /I
```

Comment: Are you *really* using **MS-DOS**? Your path example seems to indicate some kind of Windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about that

```
xcopy "C:\Users\hpara\Desktop\Test" "C:\Users\hpara\Desktop\Foo\Test" /E /H /I
```

?

Comment: This seems to result in a question for me : "Is this a file or a directory"..  Hit "F" and it copies, but I have 100 or so individual files to copy...

Comment: Found a solution:  echo f | xcopy file1.png .\subfolder\file1.png